# ReadConsoleA crashes when inside function in assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, nasm

Recently I have been trying to learn assembly x86 using NASM on a Windows platform, I am trying to make a function that reads a character from stdin ignoring any line feeds and carriage returns, but the problem is that when the function reaches the **ret** operation the program crashes, strangely when i run the function without the call to ReadConsoleA
the program finishes correctly.

Code:

```
section .bss
temp_char resb 1
bytes_written_holder resq 1

section .data 
global _start
extern GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA, ReadConsoleA, ExitProcess
section .text
getinput:
    mov rcx, -10
    call GetStdHandle

    mov  rcx, rax
    mov  rdx, temp_char
    mov  r8, 1
    mov  r9, bytes_written_holder
    push 0
    call ReadConsoleA

    mov al, [temp_char]
    cmp al, 0xa
    je getinput
    cmp al, 0xd
    je getinput
    ret
_start:    
    call getinput
    
    mov rcx, -11
    call GetStdHandle

    mov  rcx, rax
    mov  rdx, temp_char
    mov  r8, 1
    mov  r9, bytes_written_holder
    push 0
    call WriteConsoleA

    mov rcx, 0
    call ExitProcess
```

I am using NASM to assemble and GoLink to link:

```
nasm -f win64 printtest.s -o printtest.obj
GoLink.exe  /console /entry _start printtest.obj kernel32.dll
```

Comment: Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160): *The x64 Application Binary Interface (ABI) uses a four-register fast-call calling convention by default. Space is allocated on the call stack as a shadow store for callees to save those registers.*  So your 5th parameter is in the wrong place.

Comment: When you learn x86 assembly, start with 32bit programs, the calling convention is much easier.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the anwser and the advice.